# Como desplegar una web simple con HTML/CSS/JS en un servidor glassfish 4.1

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

¡Saludos!

**O tambien, ¿Como generar un '.war' a partir de una web estatica que UNICAMENTE contiene archivos html, css y js.**

Actualmente tengo un glassfish corriendo una aplicacion java, ahora, al dominio que maneja ese glassfish, quieren agregar una web estatica que se hizo con unicamente html, css y js.

Me voy al apartado de deploy application en el glasshfish (en el navegador), pero solo me acepta archivos '.war'.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer un deploy de una web simple?

Gracias de antemano.

Aclaro, es mi primera vez administrando un sitio asi, anteriormente solo habia usado NodeJS como servidor.

Comment: Debes tener tu copilado de aplicación (index.html, styles.css y demás archivos dentro de la carpeta src/main/webapp/ y configuarrlo como un proyecto de javaEE, optativamente puedes colocar un servelet para que te redirigija a index.html, similar como lo que se hace con un jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta era sumamente simple, tan simple que es algo penoso.

Solo creé un nuevo proyecto de de java web, luego una web aplication, agregue mis htmls/css/js a la carpeta web y listo, ya pude publicarlo en el glassfish.

[image: Captura de ejemplo de como crear ese proyecto.]